# Painterly Rendering, Clipping line, I'm have an error

Tags: c++, opencv

[image]
I'm making a painterly rendering.
And now I'm doing that clipping line things.
But I got this error:

```
<<unsigned><pt.x*DataType<_Tp>::channels> <<unsigned<size.p[1]*channels<>>>
```

And

```
template<typename _Tp> inline const _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1) const
{
    CV_DbgAssert( dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
        (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) &&
        CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
    return ((const _Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
}
```

Maybe this is the error that on 'Lineclipping()'

Please, tell me another good idea that clipped line.

this is my code. And I'm just a student so my codding skill is very beginner.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

random_device rd;
mt19937_64 rng(rd());
double PI = 3.141592;

int perturbLength = (rand() % 6) + 1;
int perturbRadius = ((rand() % 5) + 0) / 10;
int perturbAngle = (rand() % 15) + (-15);

int Maxlength = 10 - perturbLength;
int radius = 2 - perturbRadius;
int angle = 45 - perturbAngle;
double theta = angle*(PI / 180);

void Lineclipping(int x, int y, double theta, int len, Point2d& pt1, Point2d& pt2, Mat& EdgeMap)
{
    double length = ceil(len);
    enter code here
    float detectPT = len / length;

    for (int i = detectPT; i <= len;)
    {
        Point2d Mpt1(x + length*cos(theta), y + length*sin(theta));

        if (EdgeMap.at<uchar>(Mpt1.y, Mpt1.x) > 0)
        {
            pt1.x = Mpt1.x;
            pt1.y = Mpt1.y;
        }
        else if (i == length)
        {
            pt1.x = Mpt1.x;
            pt1.y = Mpt1.y;
        }
        i = i + detectPT;
    }
    for (int i = detectPT; i <= len;)
    {
        Point2d Mpt2(x - length*cos(theta), y - length*sin(theta));

        if (EdgeMap.at<uchar>(Mpt2.y, Mpt2.x) > 0)
        {
            pt2.x = Mpt2.x;
            pt2.y = Mpt2.y;
        }
        else if (i == length)
        {
            pt2.x = Mpt2.x;
            pt2.y = Mpt2.y;
        }
        i = i + detectPT;
    }


}

Mat EdgeDetect(Mat& referenceimg, Mat& Edge)
{
    Mat image = referenceimg.clone();

    //Make Edge Map
    Mat IntensityImg(image.size(), CV_8U, 255);
    Mat sobelx, sobely;

    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(j, i);
            uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
            uchar green = intensity.val[1];
            uchar red = intensity.val[2];
            IntensityImg.at<uchar>(j, i) = (30 * red + 59 * green + 11 * blue) / 100;

        }
    }
    GaussianBlur(IntensityImg, IntensityImg, Size(5, 5), 0.1, 0.1);
    Sobel(IntensityImg, sobelx, CV_32F, 1, 0);
    Sobel(IntensityImg, sobely, CV_32F, 0, 1);
    Mat magnitudeXY = abs(sobelx), abs(sobely);

    magnitudeXY.convertTo(Edge, CV_8U);

    Mat mask(3, 3, CV_8UC1, 1);
    morphologyEx(Edge, Edge, MORPH_ERODE, mask);

    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            Edge.at<uchar>(j, i) = (Edge.at<uchar>(j, i) > 20 ? 255 : 0);
        }
    }


    imshow("intensity", Edge);

    return Edge;
}

void paint(Mat &image, int snum)
{
    Mat Edge;

    EdgeDetect(image, Edge);

    for (int n = 0; n < snum; n++)
    {
        int x = rand() % image.cols;
        int y = rand() % image.rows;

        if (image.channels() == 1)
        {
            image.at<uchar>(x, y) = 255;
        }
        else if (image.channels() == 3)
        {

            int length = Maxlength / 2;

            Point2d pt1(x + length*cos(theta), y + length*sin(theta));
            Point2d pt2(x - length*cos(theta), y - length*sin(theta));

            Lineclipping(x, y, theta, length, fpt1, fpt2, Edge);

            //draw line
            Scalar color(image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0], image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1], image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2]);
            line(image, pt1, pt2, color, radius);

        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    Mat Img = imread("fruit.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    CV_Assert(Img.data);
    Mat resultImage = Img.clone();
    Mat sobel = Img.clone();
    int num = Img.rows*Img.cols;

    paint(resultImage, num);

    imshow("result", resultImage);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

And This is the error parts.

```
for (int i = detectPT; i <= len;)
        {
            Point2d Mpt1(x + length*cos(theta), y + length*sin(theta));

            if (EdgeMap.at<uchar>(Mpt1.y, Mpt1.x) > 0)
            {
                pt1.x = Mpt1.x;
                pt1.y = Mpt1.y;
            }
            else if (i == length)
            {
                pt1.x = Mpt1.x;
                pt1.y = Mpt1.y;
            }
            i = i + detectPT;
        }
        for (int i = detectPT; i <= len;)
        {
            Point2d Mpt2(x - length*cos(theta), y - length*sin(theta));

            if (EdgeMap.at<uchar>(Mpt2.y, Mpt2.x) > 0)
            {
                pt2.x = Mpt2.x;
                pt2.y = Mpt2.y;
            }
            else if (i == length)
            {
                pt2.x = Mpt2.x;
                pt2.y = Mpt2.y;
            }
            i = i + detectPT;
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the actual error text. The text you have listed seems like it is a piece of the error text but not the complete error. Also, is this the code you are trying to compile, because having a line like "`enter code here`" without making it a comment is going to keep this from compiling.

Comment: Please do not post code that should be part of the question into the comments. Edit your question to include it. Secondly I am not asking where the error is, but what the actual error is. I am assuming it is a compile error, but what is the actual error. Copy the error from your compiler output.

Comment: I added a picture. Anything that you need, tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Did you attach with the debugger at the point the abort was called? From the code you have added, I would assume the issue is that you have an out of range error.  You should attach at that abort call and check the values that you are passing to `EdgeMap.at`  From the code posted, it looks like you are not validating those in the `Lineclipping` method and so if either x or y is already at the limit of your array and then you add to them you are going to move beyond the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't compile this and run it, I am going to run through a possible execution and show you where you can hit this out of range error.

```
int perturbLength = (rand() % 6) + 1; // Range is 1 to 6, let's assume 4
int perturbAngle = (rand() % 15) + (-15);  // Range is -15 to -1 let's assume -14

int Maxlength = 10 - perturbLength; // 6
int angle = 45 - perturbAngle; // 44 
double theta = angle*(PI / 180); // .7679
```

Now we get into this code inside the `paint` method:

```
int x = rand() % image.cols; // Let's assume image.cols - 2
int y = rand() % image.rows; // Let's assume image.rows - 1
```

Inside of `paint` we will reach this code:

```
int length = Maxlength / 2;  // Maxlength is 6 so this is 3
Lineclipping(x, y, theta, length, fpt1, fpt2, Edge);
```

Which leads to the `Lineclipping` method and here we get a problem:

```
Point2d Mpt1(x + length*cos(theta), y + length*sin(theta));

if (EdgeMap.at<uchar>(Mpt1.y, Mpt1.x) > 0)
```

This is the problem.  Remember, x is image.cols - 2.  Now we perform the operations `x + length * cos(theta)`, which is  `(image.cols-2) + 3 * cos(.7679)`.  3 * cos(.7679) is 2.999 which whether you floor it or round it is going to cause a problem when you add it to `image.cols - 2`. If it is floored and you get 2 we have `image.cols` which causes out of range, if it is rounded then we have `image.cols + 1`, so in either case we go beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: Thank for your help! 
I edited my code and then error is disappear.
But I still have long way to go...
Anyway, Thank you!